# How do I access methods when using a jquery script?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a **Jquery Script** and whenever a drop-downlist value changes, it is supposed to take the value and pass it into a method that gets the value and calculates a price based on the value and then in the end sets a label to the new value.

Here is my **Jquery Script:**

```
@section PageScripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#paperTypeJList').change(function () {
            // trying to figure out how to pass the value to the following method
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Here is my method that I'm trying to call inside of the **Jquery Script:**

```
public decimal getNewPrice(string dropdownValue)
    {
        // do something with value and return a decimal
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: you need to use [jquery ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: The "HTML" client side has no access to the server logic without a post or form submission. As above you will need to take advantage of a technology like Ajax.

Comment: The real question is do you even need to do that?  does the operation require data access?  if not, you could probably just do the action right inside javascript.  No need for overkill.

Comment: Yes it does require data access. I have 5 different drop down lists and each time that one of their values changes then it has to recalculate the price based on their choices and it is too complicated to do it inside javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using jquery Ajax
Html :

```
 <label id="priceLabel"></label>
```

Javascript

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#paperTypeJList').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/getNewPrice?dropdownValue=" + this.value,
            async: true,
            success: function (result) {
                document.getElementById('priceLabel').innerHTML = result;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Controller

```
public decimal getNewPrice(string dropdownValue)
    {
        // do something with value and return a decimal
        return 5.72M;
    }
```

Comment: This code isn't working for me. I understand the code and what it is doing and I'm thinking that the url part is throwing things off. My dropdownlist is being created in the view index page and the method that I'm trying to call is located in the homecontroller.cs class so would that change things?

Comment: @FranklinJosephMoormann whenever your dropdown changes the code will call method in your homecontroller,Where you do the calculation and return the result ,thus you can set label in your ajax.success

Comment: I copied the code word for word and edited my method so it returns 5.72 for testing purposes and it isn't changing the label value to anything no matter what I try. I'm frustrated :(

Comment: @FranklinJosephMoormann can you post your code javascript and html

Comment: @FranklinJosephMoormann i have tried with your code it is working fine..Your element `priceLabel` is textbox or label field

Comment: I'm just getting more frustrated. I literally copied and pasted exactly what you wrote in the edited code and it isn't working. I tried putting an alert in the success area and that didn't work so it is not successful for some reason

Comment: priceLabel is a label field

Answer (score 1):

You have to send ajax call using jquery to server.

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#paperTypeJList').change(function () {
            // trying to figure out how to pass the value to the following method
      var value = $(this).val();

 $.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")',
  data: {dropdownValue:value},
  cache: false,
  success: function(response){
    alert(response);
  }
});

    });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this code but I'm getting syntax errors. Are you sure the code is correct? Isn't there supposed to be a comma after the data value? Also is there supposed to be an apostrophe before the @Url.Action?

Comment: yes , is to be put after data property, let me update

Comment: The code syntax is correct but it still isn't working. I think it is because of the url.action method. Am I supposed to change the values that you have there?

Comment: you have to pass the action name you wan to call and its controller name

Comment: in aciton you have to pass "getNewPrice" as you mentioned actionn your question, and its controller name whaterevr it is, if it TestController for exampel pass @Url.Action("getNewPrice","Test")

Comment: it is home controller so it will be @Url.Action("getNewPrice", "Home") right?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#paperTypeJList').change(function () {
            getNewPrice($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

My current code is below:

```
@section PageScripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#paperTypeJList').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/getNewPrice?dropdownValue=" + this.value,
            async: true,
            success: function (result) {
                  document.getElementById('priceLabel').innerHTML = result;
            }
        });
        });
        });
</script>
```

}

```
public decimal getNewPrice(string dropdownValue)
    {
        // do something with value and return a decimal
        return 5.72M;
    }
```